# Mixed effect random forest model for Python Windows

Tags: python, random-forest, anaconda

Does anybody know if there is a Mixed effect random forest model for Python Windows? The merf package https://anaconda.org/search?q=merf+ seems to only be available on a linux environment? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried installing "merf" on Windows 10 - it worked. I did it like this:

```
pip install merf
```